# Calling Unity method from Android performance issue

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

Currently I have a Unity game ported to Android. I had to implement bluetooth control that moves game object horizontally.

Right now I am using loop that calls `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("paddle", "changePosition", position)` with 10ms delay. I've read that this function call is not efficient at all.

Is there any way to call `changePosition` function in Unity with giving it `position` argument more efficient way?

Currently the paddle movement may have 0.5ms+ lag from time to time.

**EDIT** here's my current loop that calls for Unity function:

```
int tableRowsCounter = 0;
                int[] rawData;
                while (!abort) {
                    if (!btHandler.isAborted()) {
                        tableRowsCounter++;

                        double currentAngle = getFinalAngles()[axis];
                        currentAngle = currentAngle > 0 ? currentAngle * rightMultiplier :
                                currentAngle * leftMultiplier;

                        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Paddle", "changePosition", Double.toString(currentAngle));

                        rawData = getRawData();

                        dbHandler.addDataToArrayLists(rawData);

                        if (tableRowsCounter == 500) {
                            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                                @Override
                                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                    dbHandler.insertData();
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }.execute();
                            tableRowsCounter = 0;
                        }

                        Thread.sleep(30);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What stops you from calling that function directly?

Comment: How can I call it directly from Android?

Comment: I don't understand what is "paddle" stands for. Could you provide more context of the code?

Comment: Ah, paddle is just a game object with that name, "paddle" - the one I am trying to send message to in UnitySendMessage.

Comment: Try to make a direct reference to the 'paddle' object.
If you use SendMessage and "" you will be using reflection, and that will affect your performance.

Comment: @mayo, and how do I do that? :)

Comment: Do you have access to the Unity project? :\ 
In general terms, the use of SendMessage will affect the performance especially if is in a loop. :\
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-sendmessage-really-that-bad.38094/

Comment: btw can you show us your loop? Maybe some optimizations can be done there..
Are you waiting for the end of the frame at the end of the loop? (Anyway I'm not sure if you can do that, but maybe you can wait for some millisecs)..

Comment: I have added loop code. I do have access to the project. There I just wait for 30 ms delay, because paddle should be moving 30 frames per second (I assumed by the update() function in Unity, that the game has 30fps

Comment: mm, seems to be fine ! :\

Comment: People keep saying that I should call the function directly. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm reading a position via serial communication on an android device and need to send the position to a game. I've written an java android-plugin (long-running service app) that uses  "UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(...)" to tell the game "hey, data is ready, go and grab it from me". Then the game calls the service - using using new AndroidJavaClass(_packageName).CallStatic<string>("funcName") - to read that piece of data. The issue is its performance. It makes the game very slow.